# If $f,g$ are respectively differentiable in neighborhoods of $a,f(a)$, when does $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{g(f(a+h))-g(f(a))}{f(a+h)-f(a)}$ not exist?

Tags: real-analysis

> If $f,g$ are respectively differentiable in neighborhoods of $a,f(a)$, when does $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{g(f(a+h))-g(f(a))}{f(a+h)-f(a)}$ not exist?

Both $f$ and $g$ are $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$. I'm thinking that the limit might not exist if $f(a+h)-f(a)$ somehow takes the value $0$ in some determinate way, but it seems to me that it isn't sufficient for the denominator to be $0$ only a couple of times as $h \to 0$, given we can easily imagine that as $h \to 0$, the denominator becomes $0$ a finite number of times and then never becomes $0$ again. Is there a precise statement about when the limit might not exist? Any tips or answers are welcome.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy is there any reason why this should be so? it seems to me that if $f$ is linear, we should have $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{g(f(a+h))-g(f(a))}{f(a+h) - f(a)} = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{g(f(a+h))-g(f(a))}{h}$, and the latter is defined everywhere.

Comment: The function $g$ needs to be differentiable in a neighbourhood of $f(a)$, not $a$.

Comment: @PierreCarre thanks for catching that

Comment: Did you consider what happens if you take  a constant function $f$?

Comment: @PierreCarre there were a couple of cases where I could understand the behaviour, but I was wondering if there was a way to generalize to all cases. thankfully the answer below solves that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is differntiable at $a$, $g$ is differentiable at $f(a)$ and if $f'(a) \ne 0,$ then

$$\frac{g(f(a+h))-g(f(a))}{f(a+h) - f(a)}=\frac{g(f(a+h))-g(f(a))}{h} \cdot \frac{h}{f(a+h) - f(a)} \to (g \circ f)'(a) \cdot \frac{1}{f'(a)}=g'(f(a))$$

as $h \to 0.$

Comment: Thanks for the help!